# Why is my route bypassing a POST and turning into a GET in Play 2.4.6

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Im running play 2.4.6

I have the following in my routes file:

```
POST        /register      controllers.Auth.saveRegistration()
```

**The Problem:**

I have a form that makes a POST to /register with a payload, this works fine locally & on staging. However in production generates a subsequent GET request.

I log all routes and action methods out to my logger by override Global::onRouteRequest && Global::onRequest

**Production Logs:**

```
[info] application - [AUTH] Create::personalInfo() accessed for session
[info] application - [ROUTE] /register POST 
[info] application - [ROUTE] actionMethod.name = saveRegistration()
[info] application - [ROUTE] /register GET
```

**Staging Logs:**

```
[info] application - [AUTH] Create::personalInfo() accessed for session
[info] application - [ROUTE] /register POST
[info] application - [ROUTE] actionMethod.name = saveRegistration()
[info] application - [AUTH] Call Auth::saveRegistration
[info] application - [AUTH] Person::createOrUpdate creating new user
[info] application - [AUTH] Calling Auth::saveRegistration::AuthActions::loginPerson()
[info] application - [AUTH] Auth::saveRegistration::redirect to /myfavoriteroute
```

**Additional Context**

If the `saveRegistrationMethod()` is called, when its executed then then the first thing it *should* write should be `Call Auth::saveRegistration`

This means `saveRegistrationMethod()` is *never* called in production, and its generates a GET request instead.

Also: The browser shows a Response Code of 303 - response attached here

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Location: https://www.----.com/register
Content-Length: 20
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en-US
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Mon, 01 Aug 2016 18:18:51 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Also: Built using SBT_CLEAN=True on Heroku - verified in build logs..

**Question:**

What would cause a POST to generate a GET, and what might cause these environmental discrepencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what's happening is your application is receiving the POST request, and then sending a 303 redirect back to the browser, possibly to itself, or maybe to some other resource, which might then be redirecting back, and in accordance with the HTTP spec, the browser is making a GET request because browsers are not allowed to make a POST request after receiving a 303 redirect, they must switch to GET.

Anyway, what you need to do is have a look in your browser network console to see what the chain of requests are.  If the the browser is receiving a 303 response back to the first POST, what is the Location header that it's being redirected to?  By the way, there is nothing in Play that will automatically generate a 303 redirect, perhaps you have some filter that is redirecting that you're not aware of.

Comment: I updated the initial post to include the pastebin url of the raw 303 response - I'm not seeing any filters related to that business logic - i only see filters related to appending CORS and ExcludingCSRF via EssentialFilter.

Comment: I found a TransactionalAction decorating the Auth class that was being leveraged further down the stack. It contained a redirect for handling http vs https traffic. When it redirected, it didn't properly handle POST requests.